# Find list of values in list of ranges in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

> `set.seed(123)
>   myData<-data.frame(id=1:10, pos=21:30)
>   refData<-data.frame(id=letters[1:15], pos=sample(10:40,15))`

looking like that

```
> myData 
  id1  pos1
  1    21
  2    22
  3    23
  4    24
  5    25
  6    26
  7    27
  8    28
  9    29
 10    30
> refData
  id2  pos2
  a    18
  b    33
  c    21
  d    34
  e    35
  f    11
  g    23
  h    31
  i    22
  j    20
  k    30
  l    19
  m    32
  n    39
  o    36
```

I want an extended data frame of myData. For each row in myData i want to check if there is an entry in refData with a distance less than 2 numbers and if so, i want the IDs of refData pasted in a new column of myData. 
In the end my new data frame should look like that:

```
 id1 pos1     newColumn
   1   21 c, g, i, j, l
   2   22    c, g, i, j
   3   23       c, g, i
   4   24          g, i
   5   25             g
   6   26              
   7   27              
   8   28             k
   9   29          h, k
  10   30       h, k, m
```

Obviously, i could do that with the following loop, which works fine:

```
myData$newColumn<-rep(NA, nrow(myData))
for(i in 1:nrow(myData)){
  ww<-which(abs(refData$pos2 - myData$pos1[i]) <=  2)
  myData$newColumn[i]<-paste(refData[ww,1],collapse=", ")
}
```

But, i'm looking for a really fast way to do that, since my real data has about 10^6 entries, and my real refData has about 10^7 entries.

I really appreciate any help and ideas of a **fast** way to do that!

Comment: Have you tried reworking the for loop into something which you can use with lapply, purrr or something that can be parallelised, like mcapply?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, i have not tried that yet, but i will think about it now! I'll let you know if this works for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
myData$newColumn = lapply(myData$pos, 
                 function(x) {paste(refData$id[abs(refData$pos-x)<3],collapse=', ')})
```

Output:

```
   id pos     newColumn
1   1  21 c, g, i, j, l
2   2  22    c, g, i, j
3   3  23       c, g, i
4   4  24          g, i
5   5  25             g
6   6  26              
7   7  27              
8   8  28             k
9   9  29          h, k
10 10  30       h, k, m
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the nice and easy code! I will definitely try that and report the running time. I will also try to use your idea in mclapply as RoberMc has suggested.

Comment: I use your solution but with mcapply (on 6 cores). It still runs for more than 4 hours, but it's the best result so far. So thank you and RobertMc again!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be

```
myData$newColumn <- sapply(myData$pos, function(x) paste(refData$id[refData$pos >= x-2 & refData$pos <= x+2], collapse = ", "))
```

A benchmark with n = 1000 shows @Florian's solution slightly ahead:

```
set.seed(123)
myData<-data.frame(id=1:1000, pos=sample(21:30, 1000, replace = T))
refData<-data.frame(id=sample(letters[1:15], 1000, replace = T), pos=sample(10:40, 1000, replace = T))

myData$newColumn<-rep(NA, nrow(myData))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(for(i in 1:nrow(myData)){
  ww<-which(abs(refData$pos - myData$pos[i]) <=  2)
  myData$newColumn[i]<-paste(refData[ww, "id"],collapse=", ")
},
myData$newColumn2 <- sapply(myData$pos, function(x) paste(refData$id[refData$pos >= x-2 & refData$pos <= x+2], collapse = ", ")),
myData$newColumn3 <- lapply(myData$pos, function(x) paste(refData$id[abs(refData$pos - x) <  3], collapse = ", ")))

Unit: milliseconds

    expr
 for (i in 1:nrow(myData)) {     ww <- which(abs(refData$pos - myData$pos[i]) <= 2)     myData$newColumn[i] <- paste(refData[ww, "id"], collapse = ", ") }
                 myData$newColumn2 <- sapply(myData$pos, function(x) paste(refData$id[refData$pos >=      x - 2 & refData$pos <= x + 2], collapse = ", "))
                                    myData$newColumn3 <- lapply(myData$pos, function(x) paste(refData$id[abs(refData$pos -      x) < 3], collapse = ", "))
      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 62.97657 64.74155 70.01541 68.81024 71.02023 206.80477   100   c
 46.55872 47.90585 50.75397 50.42333 53.42990  58.01813   100  b 
 36.69362 37.34244 39.70480 38.54905 42.49614  46.27513   100 a
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and the nice comparison!

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem has two main bottlenecks -- 1) the `nrow(myData) * nrow(refData)` computations and, 2) the creation of possibly large character vectors by concatenating `refData$id`.

To overcome the first one, one way (since `myData$pos` is/can be sorted) is to use `findInterval` to locate the ranges that each `refData$pos` falls in regards to `myData$pos` +/- the allowed distance (here 2).  This way, the computational complexity gets reduced to `nrow(refData) * log(nrow(myData))` or, possibly, even less.

To save some typing:

```
a = myData$pos
b = refData$pos
```

As a start, we need to find the interval of `a + 2` where each `b` is found:

```
i = findInterval(b, a + 2L, all.inside = TRUE, left.open = TRUE)
#> i
# [1] 1 9 1 9 9 1 1 8 1 1 7 1 9 9 9
```

We specify the intervals as `(lower, upper]` and avoid falling outside of the `1:(length(a) - 1)` range so we can calculate easily the first index where `b` is 2 units away from `a`:

```
i1 = ifelse(abs(b - a[i + 1L]) <= 2, i + 1L, NA)
i2 = ifelse(abs(b - a[i]) <= 2, i, NA)
ii = pmin(i1, i2, na.rm = TRUE)
#> ii
# [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1  9  1  1  8  1 10 NA NA
```

We, also, need to locate the (`[lower, upper)`) interval of `a - 2` where each `b` falls and we find the last index of `a` where `b` is 2 units away:

```
j = findInterval(b, a - 2L, all.inside = TRUE, left.open = FALSE)
j1 = ifelse(abs(b - a[j + 1L]) <= 2, j + 1L, NA)
j2 = ifelse(abs(b - a[j]) <= 2, j, NA)
jj = pmax(j1, j2, na.rm = TRUE)
#> jj
# [1] NA NA  3 NA NA NA  5 10  4  2 10  1 10 NA NA
```

Now, we are left with the location of the first (`ii`) and last (`jj`) index of `myData$pos` (`a`) where each `refData$pos` (`b`) is located +/- 2 units away (where the missing values denote no matching).

A way to overcome the second bottleneck is to avoid it overall if we can utilize the above format to continue.

Nonetheless, to further proceed with representing the matches as concatenated `refData$id`s, we could, probably, utilize the `IRanges` package from here on to hope for something efficient:

```
library(IRanges)
nr = 1:nrow(myData)
myrng = IRanges(nr, nr)
refrng = IRanges(ifelse(is.na(ii), 0L, ii), ifelse(is.na(jj), 0L, jj))  ## replace NA with 0
ovrs = findOverlaps(myrng, refrng)
tapply(refData$id[subjectHits(ovrs)], factor(queryHits(ovrs), nr), toString)
#              1               2               3               4               5 
#"c, g, i, j, l"    "c, g, i, j"       "c, g, i"          "g, i"             "g" 
#              6               7               8               9              10 
#             NA              NA             "k"          "h, k"       "h, k, m"
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed answer. For my minimal example this works just fine, but it gives wrong results, if i extend my example like this: myData<-data.frame(id=1:10, pos=seq(21,60,4))
refData<-data.frame(id=letters[1:20], pos=sample(10:80,20)) . From what i understand, the problem occurs, as soon as myData$pos are not consecutive numbers? There is probably a way to overcome this, and if i find something i will post it.

Comment: @lWei : I've, finally, found some time to check again and edited the post. It, now, seems to work both for your original example and your example in the comments. Hope it helps.